# How important is my domain registrar if they aren't doing any of my web hosting?

Tags: domains, transfer

*Forgive me if I'm asking a noobish question, I'm quite new still.*

I recently registered a domain with **Network Solutions**, hoping to sometime later this year put up a website that I haven't finished building yet.

As of right now, *all I've done with NS is registered my domain with them*, nothing else. But I keep on reading about how Network Solutions is a terrible and overpriced registrar, and how I ought to transfer my domain over to another registrar as soon as my 60 day restriction has expired.

But the way I see it, considering I've only registered my domain with Network Solutions, the only task they'll be responsible for is pointing clients to the web address which my website will be hosted under. If I'm doing my webhosting elsewhere, what sort of complications might arise from using NS then? *(Aside from their DNS servers going down, but how likely is that?)*

(I'm still considering just moving the domain over to Hover or Bluehost as soon as I am allowed to simply because of the large amount of advice against using NS, but was wondering what sort of problems I might encounter given I don't.)

Comment: Many hosting services offer their own NS servers so you can manage your DNS records in the same setting as your server.

Comment: @Wold Thanks, I assume it's just simpler for most people to have both their registrar and host managed by the same company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly ok to keep your domain with NS or any other registrar and hosting with other company.

Though I have never faced any DNS down issue with any of our domain registrar but if you need you can register premium dns hosting from any dns service provider like

http://pk.godaddy.com/domains/dns-hosting.aspx
http://www.enom.com/dns-hosting/default.aspx
https://dnsimple.com/pricing

Network Solutions is ICANN Accredited domain registrar. I don't think they have any issues with DNS going down. But there prices are obviously high from other registrar. Most people like Godaddy that costs you reasonable with the help of some coupon codes.

My personal favorites are namesilo.com, internetbs.net and namecheap.com.

For hosting if you are going  for shared hosting, I think hostgator.com is better than bluehost but again every one has there personal favorites.

If cost is not an issue for you then you can keep your domain with your existing registrar. It is not necessary to keep your domain and hosting with same company.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how or what type of hosting you will be using (shared, VPS, dedicated) your web host will most likely be the one hosting your DNS service not your domain registrar. Plenty of domain registrars offer DNS services but if you end up using shared hosting your host will most likely provide you with nameservers to use. Even if you want to use your own domain for the nameservers the only thing you would be required to do at the domain registrar would be to register the nameservers to ensure proper GLUE.